# Allow permission to custom bash command without allowing permission to underlying command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, permissions

We have an automatic script on one of our servers, run by observing-user.  It needs to tell another script, run by primary-user, to update a log file.

The code for this is `sudo kill -UPDATE_LOG pid`

Obviously, observing-user has to have permissions to run this command.  However, I don't want to give this automatic script permission to kill processes, for obvious reasons.

I would like to do something like `alias update_log='kill -UPDATE_LOG; grant update_log on observing_user`

Comment: In continuing to search for an answer, found this:
http://superuser.com/questions/735172/how-to-prevent-sudo-users-from-running-specific-commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found an answer after changing my keywords.

See also:
[How to prevent sudo users from running specific commands?](https://superuser.com/questions/735172/how-to-prevent-sudo-users-from-running-specific-commands#answer-735286)

Step 1:

```
sudo visudo
```

The syntax is like this:

```
user host=command
```

This grants sudo access to a given command.  You can also do groups like

```
%group host=command
```

You can use ALL in any of the 3 'columns' to apply this to any host, any command, or any user.

My solution was

```
observing_user ALL=kill -USR1 *
```

Answer (score 0):

probably using

```
sudo pkill -UPDATE_LOG <process-name>
```

instead of kill  will be enough restrictive to meet your need?

Another way to adress this is to embed the command you want to offer with sudo in a custom script or exec to do this action.