# Restrict www-data user on Ubuntu to only execute certain commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-accounts

I just recently had a server get backdoored to where someone managed to get custom applications on my box under the `www-data` username (probably using my web server as the attack vector).

Since I now know that applications can be start up under `www-data`, For now, I'd like to restrict the execution to ONLY the processes I specify. I'll get into locking down the rest of hte house later.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you could for example set the programs and applications for www-data user and group through chown, like suggested in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8149/how-can-i-restrict-program-access-to-other-users) , or by setting the user and group permissions via the sudoers file, like suggested in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/735172/how-to-prevent-sudo-users-from-running-specific-commands).

Comment: Is that a whitelist or blacklist style scenario. I'd like to, by default prevent that user from executing all applications by default, but then only allow certain apps I allow.